# Operational Amplifier and MOSFET

Tags: led, mosfet, operational-amplifier

I draw a new schematic, which uses a operational amplifier to turn on a n-channel mosfet when the night comes.

I used a article from internet to make the connections of the unused operational amplifier.
I tested today the schematic and it works.
The power supply is an 12V, LM317 power supply, but I am planning to use a 12V 2A SMPS for this project.
The LED_load connector is for connecting a few leds with series resistor. The total power consumption of the leds will be about 100-200mA.

This is the schematic: [View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sdlG.jpg)
[image]

Please have a look at the schematic and tell me what you think. I am interested especially if the connection between the operational amplifier and mosfet is good.

Is the schematic correct ?

Comment: R5 is much too small. Try 10k - 100k instead, with 100k as your starting point.

Comment: Make sure the LDR does not get light from the LEDs otherwise it won’t look like night.  Increase R5 towards 1M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks okay to me.

I do wonder about the interaction of your LED and the LDR, which may cause the LED to blink despite your moderate amount of hysteresis.

You may also wish to bypass the 10K pot with 100n. I presume you've tested the LDR response and 5K-ish is about the resistance at the switching point, if not  you should do that test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Spehro Pefhany . The connection of the unused operational amplifier is also correct ?

Comment: It's perhaps a bit overly conservative in this case, but this method is 'best practice' for a unity-gain stable op-amp. You could tie the non-inverting input to pin 3 or 2 of the other op-amp and save a couple resistors at the expense of slightly more bias current.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Spehro Pefhany The connection between the operational amplifier and mosfet is correct ? The 100 ohm resistor is enought ?

Comment: Regarding the 100 ohm resistor, it has a sufficient value to limit the inrush current of the mosfets gate or it should have a bigger value ? @Spehro Pefhany

Comment: It will work fine. If you increase it to 1K or 3K it will make the hysteresis a bit snappier because it won't load the op-amp output as much. The only disadvantage to a high value is that it slows the MOSFET so it will result in more switching loss (but unless you get feedback between LED and LDR you should not be switching frequently). If you had an SOT-23 power MOSFET it would be more of a concern.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the hysterezis a bit snappier" ? @Spehro Pefhany

Comment: The positive feedback will be slowed a bit while the charge is supplied to the gate of the MOSFET due to the relatively low value. It probably will have no practical effect because other things are much slower.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Spehro Pefhany . Which is better to use for R4: 100 ohms or 1.5 Kohms ?

Comment: 1.5K is better.